# ISO week number in VBScript or VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript, iso8601, week-number

How can I get the [ISO week number](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) of some date in VBScript or VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that:

1. It is important to report the week *year* along with the week number, as the date's year could be different.
2. Several Windows components contain [a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/troubleshoot/access/functions-return-wrong-week-number) for some years' last Monday.

In my experience the simplest, clearest and most robust way to compute this is:

```
Sub WeekNum(someDate, isoWeekYear, isoWeekNumber, isoWeekDay)
  Dim nearestThursday
  isoWeekDay = WeekDay(someDate, vbMonday)
  nearestThursday = DateAdd("d", 4 - Int(isoWeekDay), someDate)
  isoWeekYear = Year(nearestThursday)
  isoWeekNumber = Int((nearestThursday - DateSerial(isoWeekYear, 1, 1)) / 7) + 1
End Sub
```

This also returns the ISO day of the week, counting from 1 for Mondays.

Comment: I guess this was meant as a self-answer question, that's fine SO encourages them but please please improve the question it needs a bit of padding and ideally should show some attempt at the problem *(even though you obviously have a solution already)*.

Comment: @Lankymart I cannot imagine which changes would improve the question. IMHO it is clear, specific, non-trivial and useful as is. As I did not find the answer to this question anywhere else I thought I should share this 'canonical' answer.

Comment: Fair enough, just usually a question like that would be deemed low quality as defined in [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Enter any date into A1 cell, then run following code...

```
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INT((R1C-DATE(YEAR(R1C-WEEKDAY(R1C-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(R1C-WEEKDAY(R1C-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)"
```

Comment: Great for Excel! But I was thinking of Access and Word as well.

Comment: Where is Excel mentioned in the question? Admittedly it's a poor question but still.

Comment: This is the code to get the current week: iThisWeek = DatePart("ww", Date) _ Exchange "Date" by your cell or variable of which you want to know the week of.

Comment: @Lankymart Herry took VBA as a hint for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it via DatePart() VBA function:

```
    Sub IsoWeek()
    Dim isoWeekNum As Byte
    Dim myDate As Date
        myDate = DateValue("01-01-2022")
        isoWeekNum = DatePart("ww", myDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
        If isoWeekNum > 52 Then ' Bug check (to avoid the bug with Mondays)
            If Format(myDate + 7, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 2 Then isoWeekNum = 1
        End If
        Debug.Print isoWeekNum
    End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed! But did you read the [warning in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datepart-function)?

Comment: Huge thank. I added a layer to avoid the bug. [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/functions-return-wrong-week-number)